# SeriLog MongoDB databaseName is null

Tags: mongodb, null, serilog

I am trying to write to a MongoDB hosted locally using Serilog.

I'm getting an error when trying to start the application

**ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'databaseName')
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull(T value, string paramName)**

My Serilog code is

```
WriteTo.MongoDB(databaseUrl: "mongodb://##.##.#.#:#####/", collectionName: "TDSlog")
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :
the database name is what comes after the databaseURL (as opposed to just using a collection name)

I changed my writeTo code to

```
.WriteTo.MongoDB(databaseUrl: "mongodb://10.60.1.15:27017/TDS", collectionName: "TDSlog")
```

and now everything is working fine.